# how to copy data in buffer?

Tags: c++, networking

I am working on network programming using epoll and I have this code.

```
            int str_len = read(m_events[i].data.fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
            printf("read %d \n", str_len);

            if(str_len == 0){
                if(!removeClient(m_events[i].data.fd))
                    break;
                close(m_events[i].data.fd);

            }
            else {
                printf("ServerManager::eventAcceptLoop, A message has been received \n");
                pushWork(buf);
            }
```

the buf is declared like this

```
buf[BUF_SIZE];
```

and I want to pass the data in the buf to the functiion "pushWork"

```
 pushWork(char * pdata){
      hand this pdata to the thread pool to parse and handle it
 }
```

I think I need to copy the data in the buf instead of pointing to the buf because it will be overriden whenever a new data comes in. Right now I do something like

```
 char *pdata = buf;
 pushWork(pdata)
```

Should I do memcopy or something else? and flush the buf?
Please let me know how I can handle this. Thanks in advance...

Comment: if you are going to use the data asynchronously, yes you need to memcopy it into a new buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can copy the data:

```
char* pdata = new char[str_len];
memcpy(pdata, buf, str_len);
pushWork(pdata);
```

At the `pushWork` end, it has to take care of freeing the data when it's done:

```
delete[] pdata;
```

---

You will also want to consider encapsulating this all into a `std::vector` so you don't have to worry about exception safety:

```
std::vector<char> data(buf, buf + str_len);
pushWork(data);
```

In this case, pushWork needs to be modified to take a `std::vector` *by value*, but the upside is that it won't have to worry about deleting the data when done, and will be fully exception-safe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also do I need to flush out the buf after pushWork to prepare for the new packet coming in?

Comment: @user800799: No. Just reuse it straight away.